# Pagination not working for structure pages

Tags: add-on, channel-entries, structure, pagination

I have my pages setup in Structure in a channel called Products ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD8Io.png)).

I'm viewing the listing of products at a URL that looks like:
**domain.com/nl/rental-shop/producten/**

If I click 'next page' the pagination active link changes, P10, P20 etc get appended to URL but the entries don't change.

Here's my template code:

```
<ol>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="product" entry_id="{structure:child_ids}" fixed_order="{structure:child_ids}" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" paginate_base="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}/" paginate="bottom" cache="yes" refresh="60" dynamic="yes" limit="10"}
    <li>{title}</li>

    {paginate}
    <li>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</li>
    {/paginate}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ol>
```

Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: You mention using a jQuery library - does that mean that you're trying to load the new pages via AJAX? Or are you using normal links that reload the page? Also, what versions of EE and Structure are you using?

Comment: Are you using the latest version (3.3.7 as of right now) of Structure? There was an edge case bug in one of the older versions that would represent itself this way.

Comment: Yep, using latest version of Structure.

Comment: Have you tried with dynamic="no" and without cache="yes" refresh="60"?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this same issue, when I learned that you need to set `paginate_base="template/page"` So lets say you have a news group and inside of that you have a index page it would be "news/index" for me that worked. With dynamic and cache set to "no"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `dynamic="no"`. For some reason that's fixed issues I've had with Structure pagination in the past. We currently use something like this on our projects:

`{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom" limit="5"}`

Comment: Tried that also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered checking your *Global Preferences* under *Channel Administration*? "Cache Dynamic Channel Queries?" should be set to **No**.