# Structure / Listing Pagination

Tags: templates, structure, pagination, path, listing

Pagination isn't working for me in Structure for a listing-template. My entries loop for the listing looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='remedy'
    limit='9'
    dynamic='no'
    orderby='title'
    sort='asc'
    paginate='bottom'
}
    <article class="remedy">
        <h4 class="remedy-title"><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h4>
        <p class="remedy-description">{remedy_rel_product backspace='2' limit='3'}<a href="{url_title_path='shop/product'}">{title}</a>, {/remedy_rel_product}&hellip;</p>
    </article>
    {paginate}
        {pagination_links}
            <ul class="pagination">
                {first_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
                {/first_page}

                {previous_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                {/previous_page}

                {page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                {/page}

                {next_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
                {/next_page}

                {last_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
                {/last_page}
            </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The links output the right path, when I click on it going to /my-page/P##, it'll just default out to the site's home-template. In the template-debugger that's also exactly what I see:

`(0.000218 / 14.59MB) Path.php Template: /`

While without the pagination-segment it shows this:

`(0.000138 / 14.59MB) Path.php Template: _templates/remedy_listing`

Which is the correct template. Any thoughts as to what's going on here? I'm running Structure 3.3.10 on EE 2.6.1.

Comment: which version of Structure?

Comment: Clarified in question (3.3.10 + EE2.6.1)

Comment: do other pages work?

Comment: Yes. Even the page without pagination works fine, it's just with the pagination segment in that it fails and defaults to my index-template.

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/pagination-not-working-for-structure-pages

Comment: That's a different issue, he still gets the same page rendered, I just get the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling/reinstalling the extension (only). If that doesnt work, what ither extensions are installed?

Comment: Ok that did the trick. Any idea what was going on?